# Is there something behind the Ubuntu Software that adds 300mb to apps?

Tags: software-center, 22.04

I just transferred to Ubuntu today and I installed Godot on it, via the Godot official website.

At first everything seems normal. I was checking out the features of the Ubuntu OS when I noticed Ubuntu Software. I looked up Godot C# on there, it exists.

Now this is where I installed Godot manually.

[image: [Size of manual install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJZ71.png)]

It saids 167M, pretty normal.

Take a look at Ubuntu Software.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryOKx.png]

Where did the extra space usage come from?

Comment: You notice your "source" is snap store right?  Snaps have everything prebundled and a base image that snaps work off of for a base OS environment, that could account for the larger filesize because of static compiled libraries, etc. packaged inside the snap and not using what's already on your filesystem - snaps are self-contained with all the libraries, etc. they need to run and don't use your system's available binaries/libraries so those also take up space in the snap container space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at a Snap package. Snap packages include dependencies and libraries.

This means that the snap package includes the mono and other dependencies of Godot Engine. Some of these dependencies can be quite large.

Comment: Nit: it won't include OpenGL, since the OpenGL implementation is up to the graphics driver on the client's PC.